# Update record in model- YII Framework

Tags: yii

I have profile page view where user can change the current password. By using findBySql & current session I checked whether the current password is correct. But I don't know how to update the records in the model in yii framework.

Comment: Is this part to be uncommented for the same purpose.? /*if(isset($_POST['Users']))
   {
  $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
  $username           = $_POST['Users']['username'];
  $password           = md5($_POST['Users']['password']);
  echo($password);exit;
  if($model->save())
   $this->redirect(array('Opening/find','id'=>$model->id));
  }*/

Answer (score 15):

You can simply follow this way to update a record in yii.

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($userId);
$user->username = 'hello world';
$user->password = 'password';
$user->update();
```

How to save a new record in yii ?

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'hello world';
$user->password = 'password';
$user->save();
```

How to delete a record in yii ?

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($userId);
$user->delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about yii active record this is a good resource http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar

It is usually as simple as that:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($userId);
$user->password = 'new_password';
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to pop-up message that password successfully changed? I rendered same change again & want to show this message on that. Thanks once again.

Comment: for start you should be redirecting to a success page $this->redirect(array('controller/view')); maybe you can ask another question about the popup and accept this answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop-up message, may you can try with Ajax validation, or Javascript to pop-up a window, after your validation ?